# Count Total Rows from Multiple Tables Which is Generated by Codeigniter -> list_tables()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count, metadata

Need suggestion to count total rows that I've generated from Codeigniter list_tables

```
$sqlx = $this->db->list_tables();
foreach ($sqlx as $table) { 
$counteachrow = $this->db->count_all($table);
echo $table; | echo $counteachrow; }

//Result for each table
| Name | Count |
-----------------
| TblA |  25   |
| TblB |  25   |
| TblC |  20   |
----------------
Total = 70 //Expected value
```

How do I get Total = 70 from code given above,
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqlx = $this->db->list_tables();
$html = "<table>
         <tr>
             <th>Table Name</th>
             <th>Rows</th>
         </tr>";

$finalCount = 0;
foreach ($sqlx as $table) {                 
   $counteachrow = $this->db->count_all($table);                    
   $html .= "<tr>
                 <td>".$table."</td>
                 <td>".$counteachrow."</td>
             </tr>";  
   $finalCount += $counteachrow;
}
$html .= "</table><br/>";
echo $html;
echo "Total = ".$finalCount."<br/>";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
select SUM(table_rows) as 'Count' from information_schema.tables 
where  table_schema='MyDb' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('table1',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from two way first you have to simple coding you can see below:

```
$tables =  $this->db->list_tables();  // given all table from data base
$counted_data = 0;

   foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
       $val =  $this->db->count_all($value);  // count all data from related table
       $counted_data += $val;  // add to total count
   }

echo $counted_data;  // desire reult you want
```

Hope it was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this Helps **num_rows()** function

```
    $result = $this->db->get('TABLE_NAME'); 
    echo $result->num_rows(); // To count result 
    print_r($result->result()); // To get total data
```